# Fill primary key of form when openened with key of current record on form

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have an access form with button to open a form to add new entities to a table with related data. When this form is opened, I would like the primary key of that new entity that is being added to be autofilled with the primary key of the record that was open on the form where the user clicked the button to open the new form... if that makes sense?

Is anything like this possible?

**Edit:**

After some more playing around with this I think I need to supply some more info:

I have the table that related entities may be added to as a "locked" datasheet view subform on my main form. When I clock the "modify button, I want to the user to be able to add new records via a different more user friendly form. When adding new records, however, an error message is shown stating that the "primary key" can not contain a null value.

This doesn't seem to occur if I leave the datasheet view subform as unlocked though. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the OpenArgs on a global variable and then on the current event of the form use it to insert it to the new Entities .

In module level

```
Global gArgsTransferred as Long
```

In form level

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
If Len(aArgsTransferred) >0 then
'Fill the Entity with the transferred argument
End if
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, I think this is close to what I need. When declaring the variable as Global in the module I am getting a compile error: "Constants, fixed-length strings, arrays, user-defined types and Declare statements not allowed as Public members of object modules". Any suggestions?

Comment: This is a strange error...remember Global variables are declared outside any function at the top of the module just under the "Option xxxx"

Comment: Yes that is where I was attempting to place it. I have resolved this - The issue was I was placing it in the Object Module for the form. I created a new Module and the error has gone away. Thanks! One follow up question: How can I 'set' that global variable when the button is pressed?

Comment: You can user the Button click but i would prefer to to assign it on the Load event of the form you want to use to insert entities....`Private Sub Form_Load()`    `If Len(Me.OpenArgs) > 0 Then`   `gArgsTransferred  = Me.OpenArgs`        `End if`   either way it works...once you "set" global variable is available until the program exits...

Comment: Awesome. Thank you for your help. This was what I needed. Out of curiosity is there a benefit to setting on the form load rather than the button click?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.

In the Button_click-event of the button you use the following code:

```
Sub btn_Click()

DoCmd.OpenForm "yourFormName", , , txtYourPrimaryKeyField

End Sub
```

This command opens the form with the record of your primary key.

Here the reference for this command: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff820845.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that command passes the key as a part of the where clause. I would like the user to be able to add new records and have the key be set to the current id of the previous record on the other form.